# What type of components necessarily pickup EM waves in antennas?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism

I understand the transmitter part of telecommunications, but what type of electrical components are used in antennas?   I understand that the transmits a signal which the antenna recieves via an EM wave, and then recreates the signal, but exactly what electrical component(s) is responsible for processing the signal?

Comment: Please narrow your questions to more specific aspects. As it is it is too broad of a scope for a single answer, or a good answer would fill many pages. Have you done any research of your own?

Comment: An antenna is just a piece of wire, which is all you need to 'pick up' the EM wave. Do you mean what components are needed to process the signal _after_ the antenna has received it?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes what components are need to process the signal.

Comment: What type of signal are you looking to process?

Comment: You need a radio receiver - the exact details depend on the frequency and type of transmission.

Comment: I think you confuse an antenna (which is typically a passive device) with the radio-devices plugged to it :)
An antenna is nothing else that a piece of metal which is capable of sending/receiving EM waves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the signal can be used directly then you don't necessarily need any components to process it. However in practice there are usually three processes required to get useful output from the receiver:-

1. A filter or tuned circuit to select the frequency you want while rejecting others.
2. An amplifier to increase the signal strength.
3. A detector or demodulator to strip off the carrier wave and recover the original baseband signal.

The simplest receiver for AM modulation is just an antenna to pick up the signal, and a diode to rectify the RF wave. If the antenna is made the right size to tune in to a particular frequency then it will provide some selectivity, which may be enough if there are no strong interfering signals.

I once built an AM radio that was simply a diode and a speaker, connected between the case of a dial telephone and mains ground. The long open-wire telephone line acted as a good enough antenna that nothing else was needed to listen to the local radio station!

Answer (score 0):

When the magnetic field part of an electromagnetic wave propagating through space  cuts a conductor - the antenna - a voltage is induced in the antenna which mimics the signal transmitted.

What's required to process that voltage in order to extract the information transmitted will depend on the way the information was transmitted; that is, on the modulation scheme used.

For example, if vanilla amplitude modulation is used to impress audio on an RF carrier at the transmit end, and if the signal from the antenna is strong enough, all that's required to recover the information sent is a diode detector followed up with some capacitance to ground, with the information appearing at the junction of the diode and the capacitor.